# Replace python for loops with vectorized method to discard missing data

Tags: python, loops, pandas, merge, vectorization

I am struggling with a data-cleansing operation. I have a large dataframe consisting of ids, portfolio months (port_months), and portfolio numbers (port), e.g.:

```
                id          port      port_months backtest_month
49025        USA0EBZ0         0            1             1
80689        USA0EBZ0         0            2             2
224952       USA0EBZ0         0            3             4
  ...           ...          ...          ... 
227370       USA03BE0         1            1             12
229804       USA03BE0         1            2             13
232262       USA03BE0         1            3             14
  ...           ...          ...          ...
```

Unfortunately, I frequently have a situation where a new id enters the system with incomplete data, e.g.:

```
                id          port      port_months backtest_month
63682        USA06W90         5            7           66
236452       USA06W90         5            8           67
238905       USA06W90         5            9           68
241358       USA06W90         5           10           69
243808       USA06W90         5           11           70
246229       USA06W90         5           12           71
```

The problem here is that the data for this id comes into the data frame at `port_months = 7`, rather than `port_months = 1`. I need to remove all such incomplete data, as another function needs to act on a data set containing only complete data. So, in this example, I need to delete the data for this id, USA06W90, for port = 5 (although you cannot see it here, there is complete data for port = 6 and so on).

I have written a simple loop which does what I want but it is incredibly slow, and I am sure that there is something more sophisticated that I can do using vectorization:

```
for id in df.id:
    for port in df.port.unique(): #so loop over ports where the current stock has some data, not those for which it is absent from the system
        first_df = df[(df.id == id) & (df.port == port) & (df.port_months == 1)] #get the 1st row from the current port's dataframe
        if first_df.empty:
            df.drop(df[(df.id == id) & (df.port == port)].index, inplace = True) # drop all the rows associated with current id and port (i.e. all port_months for current port and id)
```

This is currently taking well over 30 minutes to execute!

I have been trying to think of clever ways of using

```
groupby('id', port).apply(lambda x: x.port = x[x.port_months == 1].port)
```

or something, or trying to somehow use some trickery to construct new portfolios and do `ffill`

```
port_new = df[df.port_months == 1].groupby('id', as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.backtest_month / 12 )
```

reset index, then recombine with df by merging on index

This gives:

```
                id          port      port_months backtest_month
49025        USA0EBZ0         0            1             1
80689        USA0EBZ0         NaN          2             2
224952       USA0EBZ0         NaN          3             4
  ...           ...          ...          ... 
227370       USA03BE0         1            1             12
229804       USA03BE0         NaN          2             13
232262       USA03BE0         NaN          3             14
  ...           ...          ...          ...
```

And the nans can then be filled using

```
df.fillna['port_new'](method = 'ffill')
```

This almost works, and is lightening fast, but the problem is that you have situations where an id enters, and then leaves the data set again, so the ffill fills all those nas too, rather than removing the rows, e.g. the Nans below will be filled with 5s.

e.g.

```
                id          port      port_months backtest_month
63682        USA06W90         5            11           70
236452       USA06W90         5            12           71
238905       USA06W90       NaN             1           121
241358       USA06W90       NaN             2           122
243808       USA06W90       NaN             3           123
246229       USA06W90       NaN             4           124
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate unique portfolios, it looks like you need to create a key consisting of the `id` together with the `port`. You can then filter efficiently using [.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'backtest_month': [70, 71, 121, 122, 123],
                   'id': ['USA06W90', 'USA06W90', 'USA06W90', 'USA06W90', 'USA06W90'],
                   'port': [5, 5, 1, 1, 1],
                   'port_months': [11, 12, 1, 2, 3]})

>>> df
              id  port  port_months  backtest_month         key
63682   USA06W90     5           11              70  USA06W90_5
236452  USA06W90     5           12              71  USA06W90_5
238905  USA06W90     1            1             121  USA06W90_1
241358  USA06W90     1            2             122  USA06W90_1
243808  USA06W90     1            3             123  USA06W90_1

#  Create a unique portfolio identifier.
df['key'] = df['id'] + '_' + df.port.astype(str)

# Use .loc to locate all unique portfolios that had a `port_months` value of one.
portfolios_first_month = df.loc[df.port_months == 1, 'key'].unique()
>>> portfolios_first_month
array(['USA06W90_1'], dtype=object)

# Use .loc again to locate all portfolio keys that were previously identified above.  
# The colon indicates that all columns should be returned.
df_filtered = df.loc[df.key.isin(portfolios_first_month), :]

>>> df_filtered
              id  port  port_months  backtest_month         key
238905  USA06W90     1            1             121  USA06W90_1
241358  USA06W90     1            2             122  USA06W90_1
243808  USA06W90     1            3             123  USA06W90_1
```

It generates an array of all unique keys where port_months has a value of one (i.e. no missing data).

`df.loc[df.key.isin(portfolios_first_month), :]` then locates all of these key values and returns all columns from the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks.  So you filter on the basis that the key must be present in port_months == 1 (df.key.isin(portfolios_first_month).  If it isn't, then that particular key, which is associated with the id and its port, is filtered out.  Clever!  Presumably something similar could be done with groupby?

Comment: I don't fully understand the code however.  df.loc[df.port_months == 1, 'key'].unique().  So this creates an array with the loc of each key's port_months == 1.  And df.key.isin(portfolios_first_month), : checks that the current key has an entry.  I'm not familiar with this sort of filtering.

Comment: df['key'] = [row['id'] + '_' + str(row['port']) for _, row in df.iterrows()] this line seems to cause a memory spike (killed kernal first time and is very slow! takes 10 - 20 seconds).  Why not just do df['key'] = df['id'] + '_' + str(df['port'])? surely that would be much faster.

Comment: I am not sure what groupby would get you without a key.  I can get the `id` and `port` values, but these aren't very useful alone. I've added a more efficient way to create the key.  If you want, you can now do `gb = df.groupby(portfolios_first_month)`

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I don't quite understand how you would use gb = df.groupby(portfolios_first_month) however

Comment: `gb = df.groupby(df.key.isin(portfolios_first_month))`
`>>> gb.groups`
{False: [0, 1], True: [2, 3, 4]}
 I don't think you need it for what you've described, but you seemed set on that solution.